# Trace-zero functions in $W^{1,p}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, trace

This is an excerpt of a textbook's proof for a theorem (Trace-zero functions in $W^{1,p}$), from PDE Evans, 2nd edition, page 275.

> Next let $\zeta \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}_+)$ satisfy $$\zeta \equiv 1 \text{ on } [0,1], \zeta \equiv 0 \text{ on } \mathbb{R}_+ - [0,2], 0 \le \zeta \le 1$$ and write
>   \begin{cases}
> \zeta_m(x) := \zeta(mx_n) \quad (x \in \mathbb{R}_+^n) \\
> w_m := u(x)(1-\zeta_m).
> \end{cases}
>   Then
>   \begin{cases}
> w_{m,x_n} := u_{m,x_n}(1-\zeta_m) \\
> D_{x'}w_m = D_{x'}u(1-\zeta_m).
> \end{cases}
>   Consequently
>   \begin{align}\int_{\mathbb{R}_+^n} |Dw_n-Du|^p \, dx &\le C \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\zeta_m|^p |Du|^p \, dx + Cm^p \int_0^{2/m} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} |u|^p \, dx' dt \\
> &=:A+B \tag{10} \end{align}
>   Now $$A \rightarrow 0 \quad \text{as } m \rightarrow \infty, \tag{11}$$ since $\zeta_m \not=0$ only if $0 \le x_n \le 2/m$. To estimate the term $B$, we utilize the inequality $\text{(9)}$:
>   \begin{align}
> B &\le Cm^p\left( \int_0^{2/m} t^{p-1} \, dt \right) \left(\int_0^{2/m} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} |Du|^p \, dx' dx_n \right) \\
> &\le C \int_0^{2/m} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} |Du|^p \, dx' dx_n \rightarrow 0 \quad \text{as }m \rightarrow \infty \tag{12}
> \end{align}

My question is how I can fill in the details for $\text{(10)}$ and $\text{(12)}$? So far I've done some work and tried to resemble as close as possible to the textbooks results in some way.

For $\text{(10)}$, I did so far:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}_+^n} |Dw_m-Du|^p \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}_+^n} |Du \cdot (1-\zeta_m) - Du|^p \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}_+^n} |\zeta_m|^p |Du|^p \, dx$$
and for $\text{(12)}$ I also did (for $p > 0$ at least),
\begin{align}
B &= Cm^p \int_0^{2/m} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} |u|^p \, dx' dt \\
&= Cm^p \int_0^{2/m} \, dt \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} |u|^p \, dx' \\
&\le Cm^p \int_0^{2/m} t^{p-1} \, dt \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} |u|^p \, dx' 
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $w_m$ is a product, its gradient consists of two terms: $Du  (1-\zeta_m)$, and $u(D\zeta_m)$. So, the difference $|Dw_m-Du|$ is estimated by $|\zeta_m| |Du|+ |u||D\zeta_m|$. Next we want to show that this sum tends to zero in $L^p$.

- The  term $|\zeta_m| |Du|$ is handled by a general fact about integrable functions (*absolute continuity with respect to the set of integration*): if $\int |f|<\infty$, then for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $\int_E |f|<\epsilon$ whenever the measure of $E$ is less than $\delta$. Here the set $E$ is the intersection of support of $\zeta_m$ (which is contained in the slab $0\le x_n\le 2/m$) which the support of $|Du|$ (which is compact). The Lebesgue measure of this intersection tends to zero.
- The term $|u||D\zeta_m|$ is a bit trickier. To begin with, $|D\zeta|$ is bounded, and when we scale it to become $\zeta_m$, the gradient is multiplied by $m$. So we have to deal with $m^p\int |u|^p$, where the integral is over $0\le x_n\le 2/m$. Luckily the inequality (9) is available: it estimates the integral of $|u|^p$ over any slice (hyperplane) $u_n=t$. So we use Fubini to integrate over each such hyperplane first, and then integrate over   $0\le t\le 2/m$. At the end we again use absolute continuity, as for the first term: the integral of $|Du|^p$ over a small set is small.

Comment: If I can backtrack a bit: I tried my work again without forgetting the product rule this time, and I came up with this so far: $$\int_{\mathbb{R}_+^n} |Dw_n - Du|^p \le C \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}_+^n} |\zeta_m|^p |Du|^p \, dx +  \int_{\mathbb{R}_+^n} |u|^p |D \zeta_m|^p \, dx \right)$$ If this is correct so far, how can I get the second term of mine to equal the book's term of $B=Cm^p \int_0^{2/m} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} |u|^p \, dx' \, dt$?

Comment: @glace It's not equal to that, we have inequalities all over the place here. Also, you put the factor $m^p$ too soon. This factor comes from estimating the gradient of $\zeta_m$ by its maximum.