# Detail of a proof about about trace-zero functions in $W^{1,p}$, Thm 2 p.273 in L. Evans' PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

(PDE, Lawrence Evans, second edition 2010, § 5.5  Theorem 2, p. 273-275)

---

The little step I don't understand in the calculations does not require to state the theorem, but I simply copied it from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040533/trace-zero-functions-in-w1-p?rq=1) about that same theorem

**Theorem**  (Trace-zero functions in $W^{1,p}$):

Assume $U$ is bounded and $\partial U$ is $C^1$. Suppose furthermore that $u\in W^{1,p}$. Then

$$u\in W^{1,p}_0(U)\quad \Longleftrightarrow\quad  Tu=0\text{ on }\partial U$$

---

The step I don't understand is the two equations between (8) and (9) p.274. For those who don't have access to the book, I'll rewrite with general notations:

Let $\varphi \in C^1(\overline{\mathbb{R}}{}^n_+)$ where $\overline{\mathbb{R}}{}^n_+$ denotes the "half-space" with boundary, i.e. $\mathbf{x}:=(x', x_n)\in \overline{\mathbb{R}}{}^n_+\enspace \Leftrightarrow\enspace x' \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1},\ x_n \geq 0$. We have

$$ \lvert \varphi(x', x_n) \rvert \leq \lvert \varphi(x', 0) \rvert + \int_0^{x_n}\lvert \varphi_{x_n}(x', t) \rvert\, dt $$
($\varphi_{x_n}$ means partial derivative w.r.t. $x_n$). That's ok. Now it seems that he raises everything to the power $p$ and then integrates w.r.t. $x'$ to get
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \lvert \varphi(x', x_n) \rvert^p\, dx' \leq C \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \lvert \varphi(x', 0) \rvert^p\, dx' + x_n^{p-1}\int_0^{x_n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}}  \lvert D\varphi(x', t) \rvert^p\, dx'\, dt \right)$$
where $\lvert D\varphi(x', t) \rvert$ is the norm of the gradient following the notations of the book.

I naively imagined writing the binomial. Then I somehow need to find an upper bound and transform the product of integrals into an integral of a product (2nd term r.h.s.).

Oh, writing things down already helped me see that L. Evans indeed already performed $p-1$ integrations $\int_0^{x_n} (\cdots )\, dt $, but I still don't know how the inequality is justified, i.e. what are the suitable constant $C$

Comment: Next [step](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872726/trace-zero-functions-in-w1-p) in the theorem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you raise everything to power $p$. Then you split the right-hand side using the inequality $(a+b)^p\le 2^{p-1}a^p+2^{p-1}b^p$ which comes from the convexity of the function $t\mapsto t^p$. Then you apply Holder's inequality which gives $x_n^{p'/p}=x_n^{p-1}$. As a last step you integrate in $x'$. Do you need more details?

Comment: I did need a piece of paper. I'll write down the details: $\left( \frac{a+b}{2}\right)^p \leq \frac{a^p}{2} + \frac{b^p}{2}$ ok. Hölder: $\int_0^{x_n}\lvert \varphi_{x_n}(x', t) \rvert\, dt \leq \left(\int_0^{x_n} 1^{p/(p-1)}\, dt \right)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}\ \left( \int_0^{x_n}\lvert \varphi_{x_n}(x', t) \rvert^p\, dt\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} $. Raising to the power $p$ gives what we want (also with $\lvert \varphi_{x_n}\rvert \leq \lvert D \varphi \rvert$).